# Laravel 5.1 Mail::send doesn't work - gives 500 internal server error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I took an example from the **Laravel 5.1** documentation for *Mail* and replaced it with my send and receiver email ids.

`Mail::raw` works in the controller and if I use `Mail::send` in *tinker* it works. However, if I use `Mail::send` in the controller it doesn't work.

Everything is set up as described on the Laravel 5.1 mail page.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail . I have also cleared app cache, config cache and view cache.

```
public function sendEmailReminder(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');

        $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the source of the 500 error?

Comment: @fubar i don't know.  Mail::raw works fine in the same controller.

Comment: Check the error log and update the question with the error message. This can usually be found in `/storage/logs/laravel.log`, unless your configuration is different.

Comment: @fubar - its not logging anything.  The long files is at the same place as above.  The app_debug is true.  I am using the Log facade and added the following to my controller:  Log::emergency($error);
Log::alert($error);
Log::critical($error);
Log::error($error);
Log::warning($error);
Log::notice($error);
Log::info($error);
Log::debug($error);

Comment: Laravel should log all exceptions. This isn't something you need to do manually, again, unless you've deviated from convention. Are you running this locally?

Comment: @fubar - no on EC2 Ubuntu 14.04  The controller fails right before Mail::send.  Mail::raw is not a problem.

Comment: If you've enabled app debug then you should see the error information as well. What environment are you running it?

Comment: @sandeesh.  Ubuntu 14.04 on EC2  App debug is set to true

Comment: Does your view exist? You're trying to use the view `resources/views/emails/reminder.blade.php` with the mail.

Comment: @sandeesh yes it exists.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the view. Also how are getting the 500 error without additional information? We need more log/debug information to be able to help you.

Comment: Check whether there's anything in the server error log then. `/var/logs/apache2/...`.

Comment: Okay resolved it.  It was a write permissions issue for directories under storage/framework Once did chmod 777 on these it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error could be from the email you are trying to send from, in order to send the email successfully this email `hello@app.com` has to be a valid email address and the one register as your `MAIL_USERNAME`

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions issue for the storage/frameworks directory.  Once I changed the permissions it worked fine..

Comment: Can you be more specific and demonstrate it with code?